# Extract all rows on new sheet where driver name = NS

Tags: excel-formula

On a new excel sheet, i am trying to list **all** rows for a specific drivers name from this sheet.
I want all the rows where the drivers name is NS (or cell A1 on my new sheet). I have over 1000 rows of data and more columns than below but this gives you an idea.
The first line of data is A4:M4

Tried index/match function but unable to get it to work.

```
+------------+-------------------------------+----------------+-------------+
|    Date    |            Vehicle            |     Driver     | Drops Taken |
+------------+-------------------------------+----------------+-------------+
| 01/04/2019 | LCG - DAF 7.5 Tonner          | RL             |             |
| 01/04/2019 | GXO - Merc 3.5T Dropside      | KA             |           9 |
| 01/04/2019 | KDZ - DAF 12 Tonner           | NS             |          12 |
| 01/04/2019 | RYZ - DAF 12 Tonner           | MM             |          10 |
| 02/04/2019 | GXO - Merc 3.5T Dropside      | KA             |           8 |
| 02/04/2019 | KDZ - DAF 12 Tonner           | NS             |          12 |
| 02/04/2019 | LCG - DAF 7.5 Tonner          | RL             |             |
| 02/04/2019 | RYZ - DAF 12 Tonner           | MM             |           9 |
| 03/04/2019 | KDV - DAF 12 Tonner           | NS             |             |
| 03/04/2019 | GXO - Merc 3.5T Dropside      | KA             |           8 |
| 03/04/2019 | Hire Vehicle                  | RL             |             |
| 03/04/2019 | KDZ - DAF 12 Tonner           | NS             |           8 |
| 03/04/2019 | RYZ - DAF 12 Tonner           | MM             |           7 |
+------------+-------------------------------+----------------+-------------+
```

Comment: use an advanced filter or vba.

Comment: Just need a formula that will keep populating sheet 2 with data as i add more rows into sheet 1

Comment: The formula would be an array type formula and the number of formula needed, at least till they take the current test formula out of beta and release them to the public at large, would be too many and would slow down the calcs to a crawl.

Comment: You could use Google sheets which has the `FILTER` formula already existing.

Comment: Do you want to give `#powerquery` a go? It is an extremely simple process of three steps: 1) Add the data on Sheet1 to the Power Query Editor in excel; 2) Filter the `Driver` column by `NS`; 3) Close & Load the output table to a new worksheet.